# HBase scan values without their id

Tags: java, hbase

I am trying to create a list with HBase on Java. I can get values all together, but I am confused how to assign them to  variables.(`String bookName = ...`,`String bookAuthor = ...`)

I need to get all values which are in contribute table, and assign them to variable.

In `contribute` table, there are `id`,`author`,`name`.

```
HTable hTable = new HTable(hConn.config, "contribute");
            Scan scan = new Scan();
            scan.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("book"), Bytes.toBytes("author"));
            scan.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("book"), Bytes.toBytes("name"));
            ResultScanner scanner = hTable.getScanner(scan);
            for (Result result = scanner.next(); result != null; result = scanner.next())
            {
                for(KeyValue keyValue : result.list()) {
                    System.out.println("Qualifier : " + Bytes.toString(keyValue.getKey()) + " : Value : " + Bytes.toString(keyValue.getValue()));
                }
            }
```

`Qualifier : $dba190f6-ff45-4d5b-bf2f-d2ea75bb528fbookauthorT�� : Value : Frans Hoffman`

`Qualifier : $dba190f6-ff45-4d5b-bf2f-d2ea75bb528fbooknameT�� : Value : h32`

When I check them, `keyValue.getKey()` and `keyValue.getValue()` show every value in table. 
Is it possible to get specific value/qualify? For example, I just need to get values of `name`.

Comment: with out "id" and other column data you wanted to get name and assign it to variable. pls. see my answer. you want to prepare list of names ? Actually, question is not very clear

Comment: Yes, I am aware that question is not clear. I had no idea how I could explain my issue. But thank you anyway, you gave me the right solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My understanding :** 
You want to get only one column `name`

```
        HTable hTable = new HTable(hConn.config, "contribute");
        Scan scan = new Scan();
        scan.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("book"), Bytes.toBytes("author"));
        scan.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("book"), Bytes.toBytes("name"));
        ResultScanner scanner = hTable.getScanner(scan);

for (Result rr = scan.next() ; rr != null; rr = scan.next())  { 
NavigableMap familyMap = rr.getFamilyMap(Bytes.toBytes("book")); 
byte[] name = (byte[]) familyMap.get(Bytes.toBytes("name")); 
System.out.println(Bytes.toString(name)); // This you can assign it to variable
}
```